# bsCollapsePanel within renderUI

Tags: shiny

I am using `bsCollapse` panels (from the `shinyBS` library) heavily in an app that I am working on. I'd like to be able to define a panel on the server-side as shown in the code. The code does not run and returns an error `ERROR: argument is of length zero`. The problem seems to be that `bsCollapse` won't accept a `renderUI` argument and requires bsCollapsePanel call to be in ui.R.

I've tried having `bsCollapse()` on the server-side, which works but is clunky as the individual panels then don't expand/collapse in the same way. I've also tried including `outputOptions(output, "hipanel", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`, the idea being that my "hipanel" would be evaluated earlier, but this didn't work.

I think the key is that renderUI/uiOutput isn't returning the an object that's accepted by `bsCollapsePanel` (at least not at the right time), but I'm not sure what to do about it.

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
    output$hipanel<-renderUI({
        bsCollapsePanel("hello",helpText("It's working!"))
    })
  })
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        bsCollapse(
            bsCollapsePanel("This panel works",helpText("OK")),
            uiOutput("hipanel")
    ))))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `bsCollapse` needs a `bsCollapsePanel` so just add this in and then you can rnder whatever you want into the content:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    bsCollapse(
      bsCollapsePanel("This panel works",helpText("OK")),
      bsCollapsePanel("hello",uiOutput("hipanel"))
    )
  )))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){

  output$hipanel<- renderUI({
    helpText("It's working!")
  })
})


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

You can always dynamically create the whole thing

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("hipanel")
  )))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){

  output$hipanel<- renderUI({
    bsCollapse(
      bsCollapsePanel("This panel works",helpText("OK")),
      bsCollapsePanel("hello",helpText("It's working!"))
    )

  })
})


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm specifically looking to have `bsCollapsePanel` on the server side and `bsCollapse` in the UI. I need to generate some panels dynamically and I don't want to resort to having my entire UI inside renderUI (most of my UI is collapsible).